# Brightness filter css : Safari vs Chrome

Tags: css

I think my problem is simple, yet I can't find an easy fix :

Here's my website

http://www.paperkrop.com/contest

I use the brightness filter on the sides of the packs for perspective's accuracy.

When I'm on Chrome it looks like this :

[image: chrome pic]

When I'm on Safari (which uses -webkit-brightness like chrome) :

[image: Safari Pic]

Let's not focus on the problem with skew and scale here, but only on the brightness :

With a brightness of 0.8, Chrome (and other browsers) take it as 80% of brightness

Safari takes it as 20% of brightness

Is there any easy fix for that ?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :** Is there a way to distinct safari from chrome in css ? or making a stylesheet only for safari ? Is that a lead ?

Comment: remember that as long as a feature has a vendor prefix (ie `-webkit-`), it means that it's experimental and is not guaranteed to work perfectly from one browser to another (even browsers that use the same rendering engine).

Comment: Yes, I know, the website isn't really designed for old browsers, I'm willing to take the risk :)

Comment: My 'experimental' point is specifically about *current* browsers that require a prefix. Obviously older browsers that don't support the feature won't do the effect at all, but for the ones that do support it, if they require a prefix it means that the feature is experimental, possibly incomplete, subject to change, may have bugs, etc. If you've found something that works differently between two browsers using the same prefixed CSS, then yes, it may be a bug in one of them, or a different interpretation of the spec. The correct course of action is to report it in the browsers' bug trackers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been working a bit on this and have found that chrome < 26 and safari < 6 did the 'old model'.  The old model being 0% is normal unaffected brightness anything upto 100% makes it brighter than original and any thing negative would be darker.

The new model is 100% is unaffected.

I've used the following jquery to test which model rather than UA sniffing.

```
var oldBrightnessModel = $("<div/>").css("-webkit-filter","brightness(101%)").css("-webkit-filter")==""?true:false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the webkit prefix version as a percent? E.g.

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(90%);
```

Comment: What version of Safari are you running?

Comment: I'm using 6.0.3 (8536.28.10) (which I assume is the latest version)... Is there a css hack for safari ?

Comment: Well, I'm using this http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/ now and it works.. kindof so it's ok :)

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it sorted! :)

Answer (score 0):

The gory details: according to the [W3C Filter Effects spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html), Chrome is correct, and Safari is incorrect. The brightness filter is supposed to be a scale in RGB space (R' = cR, G' = cG, B' = cB), but the initial implementation in WebKit was a translate (R' = R + c, G' = G + c, B' = B + c). This has since been [fixed](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106674), but the change went in after Safari 6.0 was released. Chrome picked it up due to its shorter release cycle, but hopefully it should be fixed in the next Safari release as well.